# CMake cannot find Java on Linux "Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE)"

Tags: java, linux, java-8, cmake

I'm encountering a CMake error suggesting it cannot find Java (JDK I think?):

```
Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE) (found version
  "1.8.0_181")
```

However, when I run:

```
which javac
```

I get:

```
/bin/javac
```

but setting:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/bin/javac
```

and re-compiling does not solve the problem.

Anybody encountered this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like cmake is looking for `javah` not `javac`. You're using Java 1.8, so you should have javah installed. (It has been removed in a later version, and instead of `javah` you're supposed to use `javac -h`)

Make sure cmake can find the javah tool by setting JAVA_HOME so that it points at the Java 8 installation directory (typically under /usr/lib/jvm on a Linux system)

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem, but with a different cause. I post
my **problem** and **solution** below, hoping to save others' troubleshooting time.

problem:

The `CMake` reported an error much like the thread title:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE) (found version
  "11.0.7")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindJava.cmake:191 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

**analysis:**

Look at the file `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindJava.cmake`. It is found that
`_JAVA_HINTS` and `_JAVA_PATHS` do not include my java version.

**solution:**

Use a new version **CMake** that supports my java version

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the approach by [caifeng-zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12851429/caifeng-zhu) worked for me, even though the `CMake` error I got, arised in the attempt to compile ceph-libs (17.2.5-6), was slightly different:

```
  Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE Development) (found version "11.0.18")
```

I **solved** it by modifying `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindJava.cmake` only in its `_JAVA_PATHS` section, by adding the Java's explicit folder location found in my packet manager (but I also could have used `whereis java`). In my case a more recent Java version was installed (19.0.2.u7-2), so I added a line to FindJava.cmake pointing to this latter one.

My configuration is:

- Kernel: 5.15.105-1-MANJARO x86_64
- cmake: 3.26.2
- openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17 (default)
- openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have been able to solve it including the correct JAVA_HOME path (I used the java version installed by Android Studio), and its *bin* directory in the PATH variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/user/Applications/android-studio/jbr 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```